# Does a recursive setTimeout cause a stack info memory leak?

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-leaks, settimeout

I have the following scenario:

```js
let func = () => {
  //...
  let id = setTimeout(() => {
    console.trace();
    clearTimeout(id);
    func();
  }, 2000);
}

func();
```

Although I read that clearing the timeout handle will release the memory for closures and the handler itself, I am still curious if there might be a possible leak in stack information. I put the `console.trace()` call on purpose and it looks like the stack information grows indefinitely. Isn't that a concern? I know that it is not on a recursive-like stack where we might get a stack size exception but I'm still concerned about the stack information that keeps growing.

Comment: "*put the console.trace() call on purpose and it looks like the stack information grows indefinitely*" what do you mean? You just get one entry to the console each tick. Most browser consoles would even just add a counter to that line, instead of filling it in. Since the function finishes, the stack frame it takes is automatically cleared and...that's it. Where would the leak be?

Comment: Might be a dev. only thing? In the Chrome developer tools, there's an option for "Disable async stack traces"

Answer (score 0):

No. When `func` finishes execution, the stack unwinds.

If func would be recursive, the stack would look like:

```
   [init] -> func -> func -> func -> func -> func -> ....
```

In your case however it is:

```
  [init] -> func -> setTimeout
       <----     <----

  [timer] -> func -> setTimeout
      <----      <----

  [timer] -> func -> setTimeout
      <----      <----

  ...
```