# Does a recursive setTimeout call cause a closure chain memory leak?

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-leaks, settimeout

I have the following scenario:

```js
let func = () => {
  //...
  let id = setTimeout(() => {
    console.trace();
    clearTimeout(id);
    func();
  }, 2000);
}

func();
```

If we run the following code in the Chrome console for example we get the following stack trace

```
console.trace
(anonymous) @ VM89644:4
setTimeout (async)
func @ VM89644:3
(anonymous) @ VM89644:6
setTimeout (async)
func @ VM89644:3
(anonymous) @ VM89644:6
setTimeout (async)
func @ VM89644:3
(anonymous) @ VM89644:6
setTimeout (async)
func @ VM89644:3
(anonymous) @ VM89644:6
setTimeout (async)
func @ VM89644:3
(anonymous) @ VM89644:6
setTimeout (async)
func @ VM89644:3
(anonymous) @ VM89644:6
...
...
...
```

which keeps increasing on every iteration. Eventually it reaches a maximum point (i think after 35 iterations) where the chain **seems** to stop growing but I'm curious if it's simply Chrome just not displaying it. What exactly is happening?

Comment: And what about this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951520/does-a-recursive-settimeout-cause-a-stack-info-memory-leak

Comment: I did not properly communicate my concern in the previous one and it was already closed when I tried to edit it. This is why the new question was titled differently focusing on the closure part and no the stack frame part aiming to provide knowledge to both sides of the same coin in a distinct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a recursive setTimeout call cause a closure chain memory leak?

No. After firing the timer each time, the timer subsystem in the browser releases its link to the timer function, which in turn releases its link to the environment where it was created, allowing them both to be reclaimed.

> which keeps increasing on every iteration. Eventually it reaches a maximum point (i think after 35 iterations) where the chain seems to stop growing but I'm curious if it's simply Chrome just not displaying it. What exactly is happening?

This is standard memory management, things are cleaned up according to the JavaScript engine's heuristics for memory management, which don't always clean things up proactively. I suspect if you were repeatedly hitting devtools' "Collect Garbage" button (on the Memory tab), you'd notice it go back to near-baseline.

One thing that may prevent returning to near-baseline is V8's nifty [async stack traces](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-72#async-stack-traces). They're advertised as "zero cost," but of course, that can't be **completely** true because they have to keep track of the async stack information (even if just as a string).

Comment: I remain confused. I tried the Collect Garbage trick and it does not seem to bring it back to baseline. Also, if this is a linked-list type of structure, I don't see how **part** of it gets GC'ed since a reference will still point to the tail, except if the list is explicitly broken.

Comment: @Konstantine - It's not a linked list structure. 1. You run `func()`. 2. Environment for call #1 to `func()` is created. 3. Callback A is created (references env #1). 4. Timer calls callback A. 5. Callback calls `func()`. 6. Env for call #2 to `func()` is created. 7. Callback B is created (refs env #2). 7. Timer releases link to callback A. 8. Callback A and env #1 are both eligible for GC, they only reference each other, neither callback B nor env #2 references either of them. But a thought that occurs is that async stack traces may have a minor memory impact, added to the above.